# Word macro: change first character in a footnote

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2013

I have the following piece of code (not mine) which adds a tab to every footnote in MS Word (2013).

The code works fine, but it would work even better if it didn't add a tab each time but it would simply replace first character (whatever it would be - tab, space) with a tab.

That way if the macro is run twice I didn't have two tabs, etc.

```
Sub TabFootnotes()
    For s = 1 To ActiveDocument.Footnotes.Count
        ActiveDocument.Footnotes(s).Range.Select
        With Selection
            .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
            .MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
            .TypeText Text:=vbTab
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This code does exactly that: it replaces the first character (the space that separates the number from the text) with a tab. The problem is, this action amends the footnote's `Range`, so that it now includes the tab (it used to *not* include the space). So when this code is run again, something different happens because now the `Range` is different.

Comment: You are right. The code works well only if it is executed once. That's another issue with the code presented.

Comment: see if this [Link](http://www.gmayor.com/installing_macro.htm) helps

Comment: @Omar this link is about installing macros - I know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

However you do this, you will have to come up with a way to determine if the first character is replaceable or not. This is because when you change that space to something else, this something becomes a part of the footnote's `Range`. So when the macro is run another time, you'll need to know if you must keep or replace the first character.

```
Dim f As Footnote

For Each f In ActiveDocument.Footnotes
  With f.Range.Characters(1)
    If .Text = vbTab Or .Text = " " Then 'Use any other sensible detection logic here
      .Text = vbTab
    Else
      .InsertBefore vbTab
    End If
  End With
Next
```